# using model method in the django orm query

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a model which has the model method called cancelled_date which returns date when a record from the models is cancelled how can i access this method in my query set to get the particular data.

```
class Record(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    
    def cancellation_date(self):
        return cancelled_date
```

the function cancellation date returns the date the day record is cancelled

i want to filter the Cancellation date from Record model and do smething

```
records = Record.objects.all()
for record in records:
    if record.cancellation_date() == timezone.now()
```

I am able to access in like this but is there a way that i could filter only records cancellation_date which are set to today's date

Comment: Can you add the rest of the model fields and the method? The cancellation date must be derived from some other fields on the model?

Comment: @IainShelvington i have added some code could u please take a look

Comment: @jimmy how you are calculating `cancellation_date`?

Comment: @shivankgtm there are 2 other methods before this method from which the info can retreived lets say my cancellation_date is no 3 which uses no 2 which in turn uses 1 and no 1 gets some data from other model

Comment: For your query you can't use model methods in query. you have to check them separately. you can use `annotate` and `[F](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions)` depending your requirement.

Comment: @jimmy please add all your methods in full used to calculate `cancellation_date`, without them it's not possible to suggest the correct annotation/query for you to use

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use methods defined in the Model class, inside the **.filter()**.

You can use annotation instead:

```
Record.objects.annotate(
    annotated_cancellation_date=datetime.today() #assign the desired value using orm funcions
).filter(
    annotated_cancellation_date=datetime.today()
)
```